# Hide video but have it continue to play

Tags: android, video, opacity, invisible

I have an image and a video player. In portrait, it shows both. Doing landscape left, just the video shows. Doing landscape right just the image shows.

I am using the `setVisibility()` method right now to achieve that. The problem with doing:

```
myVideoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

causes the video to stop playing. Is there a way to keep it playing but also not visible to the user? Maybe like set the opacity of the VideoView to 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found a solution here. In order to make videoview invisible and keep it playing sound you simply hide it by setting alpha value.

```
mVideoView.setAlpha(0f);
```

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the z-order of the views with the `bringToFront()` method.

If you want the video to show then call `mVideoView.bringToFront()` and when you want the image to show you could use `mImageView.bringToFront()` this should work as long as the video and the image both occupy the same space on the screen.

Good luck

Comment: Hmm. Well they dont occupy the same space, however, maybe I could make a solid and just put it in front of the video and then the image on top of the solid. That sounds like it could work. Still open to other suggestions

Comment: is there a sendToBack type method?

Comment: There is no send to back method for views. Maybe you want to look at using an alpha animation where the videoView fades out (the duration of the fade could be zero so that the view is hidden instantly if you want). This would also require having a similar fade-in animation: see [this page](http://www.hascode.com/2010/09/playing-around-with-the-android-animation-framework/) for a pretty good example.